# Getting "null" when trying to access the object variable in mybatis mapper xml

Tags: java, xml, orm, mybatis, ibatis

```
public interface RawProductEvaluationEventDao 
{

public List<ProductEvaluationEvent> getEventsByTypeAndProductEvaluation(
        @Param("evaluation") ProductEvaluation evaluation,
        @Param("eventType") EventType eventType);
}
```

This is my mapper xml RawProductEvaluationEventDao.xml

```
<select id="getEventsByTypeAndProductEvaluation" resultType="ProductEvaluationEvent">
    SELECT
    id, 
    productEvaluationFk, 
    eventTimestamp,
    receiptEventTypeFk,
    isStartEvent,
    isSuccess,
    supplementalEventText,
    exceptionStackTraceText
    FROM
    productEvaluationEvent
    WHERE productEvaluationFk = #{evaluation.id}
    AND receiptEventTypeFk = #{eventType.id}
</select>
```

I have added logger and found that I am getting null value for both evaluation.id & eventType.id

```
14:47:39 DEBUG c.r.w.p.d.r.R.getEventsByTypeAndProductEvaluation - ==>  Preparing: SELECT id, productEvaluationFk, eventTimestamp, receiptEventTypeFk, isStartEvent, isSuccess, supplementalEventText, exceptionStackTraceText FROM productEvaluationEvent WHERE productEvaluationFk = ? AND receiptEventTypeFk = ? 
14:47:39 DEBUG c.r.w.p.d.r.R.getEventsByTypeAndProductEvaluation - ==>   Parameters: null, null
```

Comment: Make sure there are toString methods for evaluation and eventType, Before entering getEventsByTypeAndProductEvaluation, log.debug on them and show here?

Comment: Have you verified that you are not passing in null parameters when you call the interface method getEventsByTypeAndProductEvaluation() ?

Comment: It might be the case that your objects are not null however the ids are !!!